# Force localeResolutionCallback upon language change

Tags: flutter, localization

I'm confronted with an interesting problem. I am using "localeResolutionCallback" to set the locale on load and to detect when the user changes the language on the device. However i also want to be able to bypass it so the user can choose a separate language from the one his device is set to.

This seems to be impossible because "localeResolutionCallback" if i read the docs properly only works on load and when a device language was changed.

Does anyone know how to force it to trigger this function? I do not want to use the "locale" key of material app (which works) because i would have 2 similar operations that are conflicting and i absolutely need "localeResolutionCallback" for detection so that one wins.

Any ideas? Thanks

PS: i am indeed using a listener to rebuild materialapp but like i said it doesn't trigger "localeResolutionCallback "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "locale" as you mentionned and then just return null if it's during a device language change. Do the opposite if it's a manual language set.